# BFS algorithm does not mark all nodes in the Rotten Oranges problem on Leetcode

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, pass-by-reference, breadth-first-search

I am working on the [rotten oranges problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotting-oranges/):

> In a given grid, each cell can have one of three values:
>
> - the value 0 representing an empty cell;
> - the value 1 representing a fresh orange;
> - the value 2 representing a rotten orange.
>
> Every minute, any fresh orange that is adjacent (4-directionally) to a
> rotten orange becomes rotten.
>
> Return the minimum number of minutes that must elapse until no cell
> has a fresh orange.  If this is impossible, return -1 instead.
>
> ### Example 1:
>
> - Input: [[1,1,1],[1,1,0],[0,1,2]]
> - Output: 4

I've implemented a BFS solution. Then after finishing the BFS, I initiate another iteration to make sure that there's no fresh orange left, because if there are fresh oranges left over, then I have to return -1.

However, I find that in that final loop only some of the values were changed into 2, and some others remain at 1. I'm not sure why they are not changed to 2 as well.

```
class Solution {
    public int orangesRotting(int[][] grid) {
        //need adjacency list/matrix
        Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
        int[] count = new int[1];
        count[0] = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                if(grid[i][j] == 2) {
                    q.add("" + i + j);
                    bfs(grid, i, j, count, q);
                }
            }
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                // does NOT always print correct value: 1 is not changed to 2
                System.out.println(grid[i][j]); 
                if(grid[i][j] == 1) {
                    return -1;  // ... and so this -1 is returned when it shouldn't
                }
            }
        }
        
        return count[0];
    }
    
    private static void bfs(int[][] grid, int i, int j, int[] count,  Queue<String> q) {
        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            String s = q.remove();
            //System.out.println(s); //prints correct indices
            i = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,1));
            j = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1));
            
            if(i - 1 > 0 && grid[i - 1][j] == 1) {
                count[0]++;
                i--;
                grid[i][j] = 2;
                q.add("" + i + j);
            }
            if(i + 1 < grid.length && grid[i + 1][j] == 1) {
                count[0]++;
                i++;
                grid[i][j] = 2;
                q.add("" + i + j);
            }
            if(j - 1 > 0 && grid[i][j - 1] == 1) {
                count[0]++;
                j--;
                grid[i][j] = 2;
                q.add("" + i + j);
            }
            if(j + 1 < grid.length && grid[i][j + 1] == 1) {
                count[0]++;
                j++;
                grid[i][j] = 2;
                q.add("" + i + j);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

My code outputs -1 for the above quoted example, because it still finds a 1 in the final loop, while it shouldn't.

Could you help me figure out why this is happening?

Comment: **else if**? After entering one _if_ one could enter a second _if_. One could introduce a `nextI`.

Comment: @JoopEggen that's meant to happen because an orange could be next you 4 others that are not rotten and in one bfs iteration they should all be added to the queue

Comment: Could you explain _what_ exactly "the rotten oranges problem" is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

- The cells in column 0 or row 0 are never checked for infecting oranges. The comparison `i - 1 > 0` is not true when `i` is 1, yet you should also check `grid[0][j]`... The same issue occurs with `j`.
- By modifying `i` with `i--`, you impact the next `if` conditions, which are intended to look at the original value of `i`. So you should not change the value of `i` (nor of `j`), but assign to `grid[i-1][j]` without modification of `i`.
- In `bfs`, the `j` index is wrongly compared to `grid.length`. It should be compared against `grid[i].length` as the grid is not guaranteed to be square.
- The count is increased for *every* orange that is made rotten, but that is not what should be counted. Many oranges can turn rotten in the *same* minute, and you should only count minutes, not oranges. To count correctly you should make two changes:

  - Only make the initial call to `bfs` when you have collected all rotten oranges in the queue, since they all belong to minute 0.
  - In the `bfs` function itself, add new rotten oranges to a separate queue, so you know which ones were added in this particular minute. Then when the original queue becomes empty, move the second queue to the first, account for a next minute, and repeat.
- Not a problem, but there is no need to pass `i` and `j` as arguments to `bfs`, and instead of passing a reference to a counter, let `bfs` *return* the count.

I have tried to not change more than necessary in your code to make it work:

```
class Solution {
    public int orangesRotting(int[][] grid) {
        Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                if(grid[i][j] == 2) {
                    q.add("" + i + j);
                }
            }
        }
        // Only call BFS when all rotten oranges on "minute 0" are identified
        int count = bfs(grid, q);       
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(grid[i][j]); //does NOT print correct value, not changed to 2
                if(grid[i][j] == 1) {
                   return -1;
                }
            }
        }      
        return count;
    }
    
    private static int bfs(int[][] grid, Queue<String> q) {
        int count = 0;
        while(true) { // One iteration per minute
            // Use another queue for the next minute
            Queue<String> q2 = new LinkedList<>();
            // Populate the new queue with oranges that get rotten in this minute
            while(!q.isEmpty()) {
                String s = q.remove();
                int i = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,1));
                int j = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1));
                if(i - 1 >= 0 && grid[i - 1][j] == 1) {
                    // Do not increase the counter for each separate orange!
                    // ...and do not change the value of i or j.
                    grid[i-1][j] = 2;
                    q2.add("" + (i-1) + j);
                }
                if(i + 1 < grid.length && grid[i + 1][j] == 1) {
                    grid[i+1][j] = 2;
                    q2.add("" + (i+1) + j);
                }
                if(j - 1 >= 0 && grid[i][j - 1] == 1) {
                    grid[i][j-1] = 2;
                    q2.add("" + i + (j-1));
                }
                // Compare against the correct length
                if(j + 1 < grid[i].length && grid[i][j + 1] == 1) {
                    grid[i][j+1] = 2;
                    q2.add("" + i + (j+1));
                }
            }
            if (q2.isEmpty()) { // No new oranges were turned rotten
                return count;
            }
            // Continue for a next minute: only now increase the counter
            count++;
            q = q2;
        }
    } 
}
```

There are surely ways to make this run more efficiently, like using arrays instead of queues.

Comment: Thank you!! Your explanation clarified many things.